# send string[] as JSON

Tags: android, json, arrays

I need help sending JSON to server side. This is how it should look:

```
 "myProfile": { "languages": [ "English", "German" ] }
```

So myProfile is a JSONObject that contains "languages" which is array of strings, right?
Can someone help me send JSON to server?

```
JSONObject myProfileObject= new JSONObject();
JSONObject languagesObject = new JSONObject();

String[] languagesToServer = {"English", "German"};
languagesObject.put("languages", languagesToServer);
myProfileObject.put("myProfile", languagesObject);
```

This is creating `"myProfile": {"languages":"[Ljava.lang.String;@42b82168"}` which is obviously not good.

Can someone guide me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    JSONArray mJsonArray = new JSONArray();
    mJsonArray.put("English");
    mJsonArray.put("German");

    JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject();
    mJsonObject.put("languages", mJsonArray);

    JSONObject mObject = new JSONObject();
    mObject.put("myProfile", mJsonObject);

    System.out.println(mObject.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks, don't know why you are downvoted - it works!